# Android tabs containing list scrolling to top

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I am building an android application containing 4 tabs, each containing a fragment attached to cursor adapter. Each fragment contains a list of items.If I scrolled a lot down in any list, I have to scroll a lot back to get to the top.I want the it to behave like this: when I click on the current tab icon, it will automatically scroll back to top. How can I implement this functionality?

edit 1:
this is how the it is implemented:-

```
public class OutboxFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

OutboxListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new OutboxListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.outbox_list_item, null, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outbox, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On tab changed you can refresh your list view:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, items);
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
mListView.setSelection(0);
```

Instead of setting a new adapter (which causes ListView to reset its state), simply update the content of the adapter already set on the ListView. 
You can create a refill() method to your adapter:

```
public void refill(List<EventLog> events) {
    mEvents.clear();
    mEvents.addAll(events);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call it onTabChanged:

```
if (mListView.getAdapter() == null) {
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, items);
    mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
} else {
    ((MyAdapter)mListView.getAdapter()).refill(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your problem you need to scroll the fragment list to the top. you can do this by calling following function:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

which getlistView returns your fragment ListView;

Comment: This came up in a low quality review queue. I would likely guess that it is because you didn't add any explanation as to why you believe this is the solution. I would recommend editing your answer to explain how you came to it.